# How can I unblock a file using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file, streamwriter

I am getting error in my C# program then I try to write a file with

`new StreamWriter("myFile.dat");`

This program gets executed by other one and sometimes previous instance of the program blocks the file (don't know how and why).

Can I write the file anyway with any kind of unblocikng in my code?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I dont even think you can easily check if the file is in use without using a try catch. X-(

Comment: Yep, I use try/catch, and I get this error description in exeption message. But what to do?

Comment: Unless the other program releases the file, there is not much you can do. What are your intensions?

Comment: Don't sure, some magic like ReleaseFile() :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try opening a FileStream with FileShare.ReadWrite flag. E.g:

```
new FileStream("myFile.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

The gives more than one process the ability to write to the file.

Comment: Thanks, this is the closest one to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

> This program gets executed by other one and sometimes previous
>   instance of the program blocks the file

So, you have to use any synchronization logic between processes, instead of hacky solutions like "unlocking a file". E.g., read about [mutexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx).

Comment: Other problem is old delphi-written one, and don't have a possibility of changing it's behavior.

Comment: @ПавелОганесян: mutex is an OS primitive, first of all. Hence, Delphi code can use mutexes too. Besides, there were no any "delphi-written ones" in the question. Without synchronization logic, the only thing you can do, is to try to open file again and again, until it becomes idle. What share modes Delphi code uses?

Comment: Don't have an idea what share modes it uses, i got it as a compiled program. Anyway, thanks for mutex suggestion.